# how to work with the catboost overfitting detector

Tags: catboost

I am trying to understand the catboost overfitting detector. It is described here:

https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/overfitting-detector-docpage/#overfitting-detector

Other gradient boosting packages like lightgbm and xgboost use a parameter called early_stopping_rounds, which is easy to understand (it stops the training once the validation error hasn't decreased in early_stopping_round steps).

However I have a hard time understanding the p_value approach used by catboost. Can anyone explain how this overfitting detector works and when it stops the training?

Answer (score 20):

It's not documented on the Yandex website or at the github repository, but if you look carefully through the python code posted to github (specifically [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/648a46b3fe69ee2ee975688b1c73c0a6784e85dd/catboost/python-package/catboost/core.py)), you will see that the overfitting detector is activated by setting "od_type" in the parameters. Reviewing the recent commits on github, the catboost developers also recently implemented a tool similar to the "early_stopping_rounds" parameter used by lightGBM and xgboost, called "Iter."
To set the number of rounds after the most recent best iteration to wait before stopping, provide a numeric value in the "od_wait" parameter.

For example:

```
fit_param <- list(
  iterations = 500,
  thread_count = 10,
  loss_function = "Logloss",
  depth = 6,
  learning_rate = 0.03,
  od_type = "Iter",
  od_wait = 100
)
```

I am using the catboost library with R 3.4.1. I have found that setting the "od_type" and "od_wait" parameters in the fit_param list works well for my purposes.

I realize this is not answering your question about the way to use the p_value approach also implemented by the catboost developers; unfortunately I cannot help you there. Hopefully someone else can explain that setting to the both of us.

Comment: thanks so much for sharing this! I did not know about the od_type and od_wait parameters. This is really appreciated!

Comment: No problem! The Yandex documentation isn't perfect, so I started poking through the python code over the weekend to see what might be missing. It was a very happy discovery for me, too.

Answer (score 14):

Catboost now supports `early_stopping_rounds`: [fit method parameters](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_fit.html)

> Sets the overfitting detector type to Iter and stops the training
>   after the specified number of iterations since the iteration with the
>   optimal metric value.

This works very much like `early_stopping_rounds` in xgboost.

Here is an example:

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor, Pool

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np 

y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
X = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, 1))
X[:, 0] += y * 2

X_train, X_eval, y_train, y_eval = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

train_pool = Pool(X, y)
eval_pool = Pool(X_eval, y_eval)

model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=1000, learning_rate=0.1)

model.fit(X, y, eval_set=eval_pool, early_stopping_rounds=10)
```

The result should be something like this:

```
522:    learn: 0.3994718        test: 0.4294720 best: 0.4292901 (514)   total: 957ms    remaining: 873ms
523:    learn: 0.3994580        test: 0.4294614 best: 0.4292901 (514)   total: 958ms    remaining: 870ms
524:    learn: 0.3994495        test: 0.4294806 best: 0.4292901 (514)   total: 959ms    remaining: 867ms
Stopped by overfitting detector  (10 iterations wait)

bestTest = 0.4292900745
bestIteration = 514

Shrink model to first 515 iterations.
```

Answer (score 1):

early_stopping_rounds takes into account both od_type='Iter' and od_wait parameters. No need to individually set both od_type and od_wait, just set early_stopping_rounds parameter.